# Is the MAC address of the TAP-Windows adapter visible to the network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, openvpn, network-adapter, mac-address

When using the TAP-Windows adapter v9, such as when connecting with the OpenVPN GUI, does a router see the MAC address of the hardware Wi-Fi network card and the TAP adapter or just the Wi-Fi network card?

My own router only displays the hardware MAC address. I'm not sure whether this is due to a limitation to my router or its interface. I don't think the TAP MAC address is exposed, however when using a program displaying network traffic (not WireShark), it displays packets being received and sent for both the TAP adapter and the Wi-Fi network card.

Some light googling also brought be these users needing the MAC address of the TAP adapter to be a certain value - (albeit in a different setup) - also lead me to wonder 
(https://www.sparklabs.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=247)
(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tunnelblick-discuss/s4HweULDrKc) (https://serverfault.com/questions/930571/how-to-setup-my-mac-address-to-be-static-using-openvpn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Spoofing of the TAP adapter as a precaution is not possible at the moment: (https://github.com/OpenVPN/tap-windows6/issues/97)

Would greatly appreciate answers and thoughtful insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A** router? Yes, if your OpenVPN tunnel is actually in `dev-type tap` mode (which sends Ethernet-layer packets), then the VPN server – which is a router – will see your TAP interface's MAC address, as will other clients of the same VPN connection.

Fortunately, most OpenVPN connections are in 'tun' mode (which sends IP-layer packets) – they merely use a TAP interface on Windows because for a long time that was the only good driver for virtual VPN interfaces. But because the actual connection is in 'tun' mode, all Ethernet headers are simply discarded before OpenVPN sends the packet, so the MAC address is not seen by any device at all.

(But there's a huge exception to that: if you happen to have legacy NetBIOS/SMBv1 services enabled and not blocked by a firewall, they'll respond to NBSTAT calls which will reveal the inbound interface's MAC address even to distant hosts.)

The MAC address of an interface is generally not seen by devices reaching you through *other* interfaces, VPN or not. So even if you use 'tap'-mode VPN tunnels, their MAC address will remain unknown to your *home* router (or whichever physical network you're connected to).